# I Just Updated my Ubuntu guess to 23.10 then I Notice Some Color Mismatch Across its Apps

Tags: files, settings, 23.10

[I just want settings and Files to have same contrast  and why the title bar of gnome terminal looks like straight from Ubuntu 23.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEjvH.png)

Comment: Please post a (ideally well written) description of the problem rather than just a link to an image https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask